# Using :key on template with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Any ideas how to use key inside a template?

My sample code

```
<template v-if="_hasDeposit" >
    <template v-for="(_item, key) in item.client.deposits" :key="key">
        <td><p class="title">{{_item.balance_formatted}}</p></td>
        <td>
            
            <amount-input :disabled="inputDisabled(item.id) 
                "@amountEncoded="amountEncoded($event,'deposit',_item.deposit_account_id)"  
                :account_info="_item" 
                :tabindex="tabIndex('loan',key)" 
                :add_class="errorAddClass(item.id,'deposit')"
                >
            </amount-input>
        <div class="text-danger" v-if="hasInputError(item.id,'deposit',key)" >
            {{inputErrorMessage(item.id,['amount','repayment_date'],'deposit',key)}}
        </div>
        </td>
            
    </template>
</template>
```

The error is : `<template> cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.`

But in my case i need it to be in the `<template></template>` for the parent of `<td></td>`

Comment: Use div instead of second temple.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist div is not applicable. It is a <td> and its not okay to used <div> as parent of <td> it will destroy the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `key` variable of cycle without setting the `:key` attrubite to the template. However, you can key child `<td>` elements like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/b4oyragL/, that's mentioned in this issue https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/447

So in your case it will be

```
<template v-if="_hasDeposit" >
    <template v-for="(_item, key) in item.client.deposits">
        <td :key="key + 'title'"><p class="title">{{_item.balance_formatted}}</p></td>
        <td :key="key + 'input'">
            
            <amount-input :disabled="inputDisabled(item.id) 
                "@amountEncoded="amountEncoded($event,'deposit',_item.deposit_account_id)"  
                :account_info="_item" 
                :tabindex="tabIndex('loan',key)" 
                :add_class="errorAddClass(item.id,'deposit')"
                >
            </amount-input>
        <div class="text-danger" v-if="hasInputError(item.id,'deposit',key)" >
            {{inputErrorMessage(item.id,['amount','repayment_date'],'deposit',key)}}
        </div>
        </td>
            
    </template>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried this before and i thought it didn't work. Since im using dark theme on my application and the text is also black. I thought it's not working which is not visible yet it was displayed   . My Bad. Anyways Thanks for this.